# What is the latest flutter version for MacOS BigSur 11.7 and possibly it's latest XCode version 13.2.1?

Tags: flutter, xcode, macos-big-sur

Hello I am Planning on starting to develop my apps for Apple Platform and for now I have a Macbook Air (Early 2014) with MacOS BigSur 11.7. So my question is, what is the most recent and compatible flutter version for this Macbook.

Any Suggestions are welcome thank you!

I have Search around the internet so far I have found that the maximum XCode Version will be 13.2.1 and for flutter it is mentioned on their website that we can install it on MacOS Catalina 10.15 and later meaning the latest is installable on my mac but still on the same website I see there is a limit to Xcode 15 which is not compatible with this macbook.